# Cannot drag an app from Launchpad to trash

Tags: applications, trash, macos

I recently had an app called ZipCloud appear in my Launchpad applications - overtime I drag it to trash, it simply goes back. How do I delete it?

The page http://support.zipcloud.com/question/110/how-do-i-uninstall-zip-cloud says to drag to trash

Why do some things not go into trash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Managed to delete it by opening the Applications folder in Finder and right clicking and selecting 'Move to trash'

The dragging operation is obviously different to the 'Move to trash' option in some way

Comment: "Obviously". But what about the apps for which the "Move to trash" option doesn't show up?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but for completeness I wanted to provide the correct answer for future searches.

For apps installed from the Mac App Store (MAS), do this:

Open the Launchpad.  Click and hold on the app you wish to delete.  When you do this you'll see the apps start to wiggle just like they do on iPhones and iPads, and little X buttons will appear on the icons of apps that can be deleted.  Click this X, confirm, and the app will be uninstalled from your Mac.

For non-MAS Applications, follow the steps mentioned in the accepted answer above.

Comment: But how you know if its installed from store then ? You should try it ? Its really bad usability bug leaved like this for couple of years.

Comment: Only MAS apps show an X when the icons are wiggling.  Non-MAS apps do not, and must be uninstalled using the old drag-to-trash method or by using an uninstaller tool provided by the app creators.  I completely agree with you that it breaks user flow when you need to use two or more methods just to uninstall an app, and Apple are usually better at things than this.